# How to get animation plot to display time on the x-axis as opposed to numerical value

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am reading data in from a csv file and plotting a "live stream" using matplotlib animation. Everything is working fine except that I want to display time on the x-axis as opposed to the "matplotlib.dates.date2num" values. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import datetime
from numpy import genfromtxt


cv = numpy.genfromtxt ('file.csv', delimiter=",")
second = cv[:,0]
third = cv[:,2]
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.%f'
data = numpy.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=2,names=['t', 'in', 'x', 'y','z'], dtype=['object', 'int8', 'float', 'float', 'float'])                  
d = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i.decode('ascii'), FMT) for i in data['t']]

conversion3 = [matplotlib.dates.date2num(j) for j in d]
mytime3 = numpy.array(conversion3)

x = mytime3
y = third               
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-')
ax.margins(0.05)

def init():
    line.set_data(x[:2],y[:2])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    win = 150
    imin = min(max(0, i - win), x.size - win)
    xdata = x[imin:i]
    ydata = y[imin:i]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=25)

plt.show()
```

The csv file is of the form:

```
2016-07-11-095303.810,1,79
2016-07-11-095303.900,1,77
2016-07-11-095303.990,1,59
2016-07-11-095304.080,1,48
2016-07-11-095304.170,1,48
2016-07-11-095304.260,1,77
2016-07-11-095304.350,1,81
2016-07-11-095304.440,1,63
2016-07-11-095304.530,1,54
2016-07-11-095304.620,1,29
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `DateFormatter` as in the [dates example](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html)? Is it actually necessary to convert your dates to numbers at all? Why not plot the dates directly? Note that you would help others help you by providing a [mcve] of the issue, such that people do not need to recreate some sample data themselves.

Comment: I have tried using a DateFormatter but ended up with a blank canvas. I will attempt to plot the dates directly

Comment: I have attempted to plot the dates directly but again end up with a blank canvas. Is there a certain format that the dates need to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `plot_date` instead of `plot`, this will format the ticks automatically. You then should plot the dates, not the converted numbers.

The following runs fine:

```
u = u"""2016-07-11-095303.810,1,79
2016-07-11-095303.900,1,77
2016-07-11-095303.990,1,59
2016-07-11-095304.080,1,48
2016-07-11-095304.170,1,48
2016-07-11-095304.260,1,77
2016-07-11-095304.350,1,81
2016-07-11-095304.440,1,63
2016-07-11-095304.530,1,54
2016-07-11-095304.620,1,29"""

import io
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import datetime
from numpy import genfromtxt


cv = numpy.genfromtxt (io.StringIO(u), delimiter=",")
second = cv[:,0]
third = cv[:,2]
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.%f'
data = numpy.genfromtxt(io.StringIO(u), delimiter=',', skip_header=2,
                        names=['t', 'in', 'x', 'y','z'], 
                        dtype=['object', 'int8', 'float'])
d = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i.decode('ascii'), FMT) for i in data['t']]


x = d
y = data["x"]        
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot_date([], [], 'b-')
ax.margins(0.05)

def init():
    line.set_data(x[:2],y[:2])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    imin = 0 #min(max(0, i - win), x.size - win)
    xdata = x[imin:i+2]
    ydata = y[imin:i+2]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=7,init_func=init, interval=150)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That code works great! However, when I try to re-implement the sliding window, I end up with a blank canvas? I want the sliding window for working with my larger csv file